# Send rails information from one window onto another window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two windows open, and window B just did some processing to get some results. I wish to use these results as the input for another set of processing.

However, I wish to close the second window and start the processing on the first window. I can use javascript to accomplish this, but I don't know how to send the information from the second window onto the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) is what you're looking for. It is supported by these browsers: FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari(5?), Opera10+.